# Find a value and .filldown over multiple subsequent ranges?

Tags: excel, fill, vba

VBA newbie here.  I have a dynamic list of multiple groups.  Each group lists the leader of the group at the top with the members of the group below.  There is a primary key in Column A next to each listed person.  I want to take the leader's key # and apply it to Column F for the leader and each member of the group, such that each member has their own primary key # in Column A *and* is associated with their *leader's* primary key # in Column F.  Here are two images of what I need for the before and after:

**Before**
[image: Before:]

**After**
[image: After:]

Here is the code I am playing around with conceptually:

```
Sub Apply_Leader_Code()

Dim wSht As Worksheet
Dim lStart As Long, lEnd As Long, lLdrID As Long

Set wSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Upload")

With wSht.Range("A1:G" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    lStart = .Rows.Find("78") 'Find the first row for each group
    lEnd = .Rows.FindNext("78") - 1 'Find the last row for each group
If .Range("G" & lStart & ":G" & lEnd).Value = "" Then 
        'If there is no leader ID yet, then continue...
    lLdrID = .Cells(lStart, 1).Value 'Assign leader's primary key to the variable
    .Cells(lStart, 7).Value = lLdrID 'Place lLdrID value into Column G
    .Range("F" & lStart & ":F" & lEnd).FillDown 'Fill value to end of group range
Else
        '..otherwise, set start/end rows for next group.
    lStart = .Rows.FindNext("Leader")
    lEnd = .Rows.FindNext("Leader") - 1
End If
End With
End Sub
```

The above code isn't actually applicable, but I hope represents what I think is a reasonable way to solve this problem.  I can (maybe?) figure out how to do this for the first group, but how do I then perform the same `.FillDown` function for each subsequent group?

--**EDIT**--

In regards to Siddarth Rout's answer below, here is my newer code:

```
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
Range("G3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=78,RC[-6],R[-1]C)"
Range("G3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G3:G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

I used the Macro creator in Excel and then edited it to what I thought would enable it to have a dynamic range instead of a set range.  Now I'm getting a 400 error.  Any ideas why?  Any ideas on how to input the formulas w/o "selecting" the range?  I am gathering that many programmers think that selecting cells is bad programming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need VBA for this? This can be achieved using excel formulas

Formula in Cell `G2`

`=A2`

Formula in Cell `G3`

`=IF(F3=78,A3,G2)`

now simply copy the formula from `G3` down to `G14`

[image]

If you still need VBA then simply record a macro for the above steps and amend it :)

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

Yes `.Select` should be avoided. 
[INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Also no need to use `R1C1` format. You can directly specify the formula

And one more thing. You don't need to use `Autofill`. You can skip that step by directly filling all the relevant cells with the relevant formula in **ONE GO**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last cell in Col A which has data
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Enter first formula
        .Range("G2").Formula = "=A2"

        '~~> Enter 2nd formula in all the
        '~~> cells in one go rather than autofill
        .Range("G3:G" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(F3=78,A3,G2)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: *sigh* Of course it has a simple answer and I was over-complicating it!  Thanks, Siddharth.  I have edited my initial question because now I'm getting a 400 error when I try to apply a macro created using your suggestion.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do. Works flawlessly. And thanks for the article on `.Select`, too =)